# jQuery: find the longest string from table td

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone please tell me how can I find the longest string from a table column?

Ex: I need to find the longest name from `td` with class `name` and if name is longer than 50 chars do something, else do something.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>val1</th>
    <th>val2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name short</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.name {
  width:70%;
}
.first_value {
  width: 20%;
}
.second_value {
  width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: find longest and find over 50 chars are two different things

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward task: collect all `td.name`, go through them checking for max .text() length, storing that value, then analyze it. What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between "find the longest" and "more than 50 chars".

You can loop all table cells and check it's value:

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = $('table tbody td'),
      tr = 0,
      td = 0,
      l = 0;
  $.each(elem, function() {
    var cell = $(this),
        cellLength = cell.text().length;
    
    if( cellLength > l ) {
      l = cellLength;
      tr = cell.closest('tr').index();
      td = cell.index();
    }
  });
  $('#result').text( 'The longest value is inside row '+(tr+1)+' and column '+(td+1) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>val1</th>
    <th>val2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name short</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="color:red" id="result"></div>
```

If you want do change the cells with a value longer than 50 chars, use this:

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = $('table tbody td');
  $.each(elem, function() {
    if( $(this).text().length > 50 ) {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>val1</th>
    <th>val2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name short</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">name name name name name name name name name name name name</td>
      <td class="first_value">val1</td>
      <td class="second_value">val2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="color:red" id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each name element using the `.each()` method and use this to get the text:

```
var longestName = "";
$('table td .name').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > longestName){
        longestName = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Then you can use an if statement to see if it is over 50 characters:

```
if(longestName.length > 50){
    //do something
} else{
    // do this instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var maxlen=0;
var tdLongest;
$('table td .name').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > maxlen)
    {
        maxlen = $(this).text().length;
        tdLongest = $(this);
    }
});
```

`tdLongest` object contains the longest name text td so you can check it's length than after do whatever you want to do.

```
if(tdLongest.text().length > 50)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: boop boop sorry didn't see someone already posted the answer.

Comment: @Glubus you don't need to do that someone have posted the answer or not. and please check timing for your information

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over each element holding the class "name". Then check the length of the content of each row, and keep a maximum to track your current longest name.
Then when you've found all rows, check your current longest name, and see if it's longer than 50.

```
var currentMax = -1;
var currentName = "";
    $(".name").each(function(index, value) {
        var nameValue = $(value).html();
        if(nameValue.length > currentMax) {
            currentMax = nameValue.length;
            currentName = nameValue;
        }
    });

    if(currentMax > 50) {
        //do stuff with currentName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering with regex to find strings with length bigger than 50:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regex = new RegExp(/^.{51,}$/); 
    $("td.name").filter(function () {
        if(regex.test($(this).text())){
            console.log($(this).text());//or do something
        }
    });
});
```